# ArcGIS Javascript Viewer with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm certain this question must have been asked/answered, but I just can't find it.

I'm running ArcGIS Server and want to build a basic viewer that points to my locally hosted services.  I'm not interested in doing anything with ArcGIS.com; however all the examples hosted at esri illustrate interfacing with ArcGIS.com.

How can I point to my local map?

Alternatively, can you point me to where I can find the answer (as I'm certain this must have been asked already)

Comment: I explored all the resources that I was directed too, but none were totally sufficient.  I eventually figured it out, but IMHO I think there should be a comprehensive guide to utilizing the api with Arc Server and NOT exclusively publish examples that utilize Arc online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a local Mapservice which is dynamic (i.e. not cached)

Please have a look at this sample: [Dynamic map service](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamic.html)

You will see that they are adding a map service using the following line of code:

```
var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
"http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer", {
          "opacity":0.5, 
          "imageParameters":imageParameters
        });
```

You need to provide the URL of the REST endpoint of your dynamic map service.

If the hostname of your server is `myserver` and the name of your service is say `myMapService`, you can use the following line of code:

```
var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
"http://myserver/ArcGIS/rest/services/myMapService/MapServer", {
          "opacity":1, /* 100 % opacity */
          "imageParameters":imageParameters
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get started with [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/). Using [this tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jstutorials/intro_firstmap_amd.html) will help you build your first application

Comment: I've been pouring over this for a long time now.  But what I can't find is where to put the reference to my local service?  This tutorial nicely skips over this.

Comment: I also have no idea where to put the js file when I've written it.

Comment: you would need to put the js/html/css files in the wwwroot folder on your server. Look through the ArcGIS Server help for more information: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_creating_web_GIS_applications/0154000004z1000000/

Comment: Ok, but my first problem still remains.  How do I reference a local service?