# Displaying Geodatabase Published Map On ArcGIS Server (JavaScript API)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I Google this a lot but unfortunately I didn't find any useful Tutorial for this.Can you please let me know how I can Put my published Geodatabase/ shapefile on the top of a ArcGIS JavaScript API map?

I have already published my geodatabase map as a Service now I do not know how to display that map on the top of a javaScript powered map in a page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-122.45,37.75], // long, lat
          zoom: 13,
          sliderStyle: "small"
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73640/arcgis-javascript-viewer-with-arcgis-server/73671#73671

Answer (score 1):

The sample you have is for an ArcGIS Online webmap and not a specific service from ArcGIS Server.

If you refer to the ArcGIS Javascript API reference and samples, you will see that the [following sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamic.html) solves your problem (assuming its a dynamic map service.

Swap out the URL to your own ArcGIS Server service.  This URL is the REST endpoint for your map service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Create Map and add a dynamic layer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css"/>
    <style>
      html, body, #mapDiv{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
        "esri/layers/ImageParameters"
      ], function (
        Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters) {

        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          sliderOrientation : "horizontal"
        });

        var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
        imageParameters.format = "jpeg"; //set the image type to PNG24, note default is PNG8.

        //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
        var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer", {
          "opacity" : 0.5,
          "imageParameters" : imageParameters
        });

        map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```